# Split list in python when same values occurs into a list of sublists

Tags: python

Using python, I need to split my_list = ['1','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','5'] into a list with sublists that avoid the same value.  Correct output = [['1','2','3','4','5'],['2','3','4'],['3']]

Comment: how would you decide number of elements in each sublist?

Comment: @GodIsOne OP is beginning at start and then consumes elements, next iteration used elements are not there anymore

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the most efficient approach but effective nonetheless:

```
my_list = ['1','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','5']
output = []

for e in my_list:
    for f in output:
        if not e in f:
            f.append(e)
            break
    else:
        output.append([e])

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['3']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I assumed you are indexing every unique element with its occurrence and also sorted the result list to better suit your desired output.

```
uniques = list(set(my_list))
uniques.sort()

unique_counts = {unique:my_list.count(unique) for unique in uniques}
new_list = []
for _ in range(max(unique_counts.values())):
    new_list.append([])
for unique,count in unique_counts.items():
    for i in range(count):
        new_list[i].append(unique)
```

The output for new_list is

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['3']]
```

Answer (score 2):

By using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for recognizing the maximum number of the needed sublists and then distributing consecutive unique keys on sublists according to their frequencies:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['1','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','5']
cnts = Counter(my_list)
res = [[] for i in range(cnts.most_common(1).pop()[1])]

for k in cnts.keys():
    for j in range(cnts[k]):
        res[j].append(k)
print(res)
```

---

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it based on getting unique values and counts using list comprehension.

```
my_list = ['1','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','5']

unique = [val for i,val in enumerate(my_list) if val not in my_list[0:i]]
counts = [my_list.count(val) for val in unique]

output = [[val for val,ct in zip(unique, counts) if ct > i] for i in range(max(counts))]
```